# Failed String Parsing to LocalDateTime using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-parsing

I am trying to parse a simple string [08/May/2020:09:14:05 +0000] to LocalDateTime using DateTimeFormatter and LocalDateTime but it seems that it does not work for some reasons. I have tried different changes to the format like DD, hh, X, x, or Z but it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
String log = "[08/May/2020:09:14:05 +0000]";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[d/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss x]");
LocalDateTime odt = LocalDateTime.parse(log, fmt);
System.out.println(odt);
```

Any guess?

Comment: `[...]` has special meaning in a date format pattern (means "optional"), so you need to quote them: `"'['d/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss x']'"`

Comment: @Andreas it still didn't work

Comment: When using text fields, it's always best to specify the language, so it won't try to use e.g. German month names. Also, the year should use `uuuu`: `ofPattern("'['d/MMM/uuuu:HH:mm:ss x']'", Locale.US)`

Comment: Since the string includes a time zone offset, are you sure you want to parse to `LocalDateTime`, and not `OffsetDateTime`?

Comment: @Andreas still does not work somehow, I have tried with OffsetDateTime as well but no luck

Comment: Use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'['dd/MMM/uuuu:HH:mm:ss xx']'", Locale.US)`

Answer (score 2):

All credit goes to Andreas. His suggestion in the comments is good enough to be posted as an answer.

```
    String log = "[08/May/2020:09:14:05 +0000]";
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'['dd/MMM/uuuu:HH:mm:ss xx']'", Locale.US);
    LocalDateTime odt = LocalDateTime.parse(log, fmt);
    System.out.println(odt);
```

Output is:

> 2020-05-08T09:14:05

In the format pattern string the square brackets `[` and `]` are (usually) used to enclose optional parts of the format. Since you want to specify that literal square brackets are in the date-time string, enclose them in apostrophes in the format pattern string. This cancels the meaning that the brackets have otherwise.

Also use `xx` for UTC offset with hours and minutes without colon such as `+0000`.

Finally always specify locale when the string includes locale sensitive parts such as a month abbreviation. In this case I think that any English-speaking locale will work, including `Locale.ENGLISH`, `Locale.ROOT`, `Locale.UK`, `Locale.US` and many others.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the square brackets.  And add another x to the timezone format.

```
log = log.replaceAll("\\[", "");
log = log.replaceAll("]", "");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[d/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss xx]");
```

You can add the brackets back in with

```
System.out.println("[" + odt + "]");
```

Also, you may want to add another 'd' to the day of the month.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss xx]");
```